# Javascript not firing on keyup under ".every"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a DataTable that has frezzed columns. Now I also placed a search input type text as footer. Now I have this script on keyup which is under on a .every function but its not firing up. Can anyone help?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example tfoot th').each( function () {
    var title = $('#example thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
    $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="'+title+'" />' );
} );
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    setTimeout:     "50",
    scrollY:        "350px",
    scrollX:        true,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    paging:         false,
    heightMatch:    "auto",
    columnFilter:   true,
    fixedColumns:   {
    leftColumns: 2
    },
});
table.columns().every( function () {
    var that = this;

    $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup', function () {
        alert('NAGIBA');
        /*that
            .search( this.value )
            .draw();*/
    } );
} );

});
</script>
```

Comment: create a demo that reproduces issue

Comment: Are you sure this.footer() is returning something? Is it finding an input?

Comment: How do i check if i may ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi use '**keyup change**' instead of '**keyup**' as showb below.

```
$( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
    alert('NAGIBA');
    /*that
    .search( this.value )
    .draw();*/
} );
```

For more details check this [link](http://reddyinfosoft.blogspot.in/2016/12/jquery-datatable-in-mvc.html)
and this [link](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html)

Comment: Just a question. Why does this jquery affect the not frozen columns. It does not work on frozen columns?

Comment: Hi Pro, are you sure? I think it should work on frozen columns also(I didnt checked).

Comment: Hi Vara. Yep, I doubled check it. It does not work on mine but it should work based on the source of the code.http://www.cscc.edu/_resources/app-data/datatables/examples/api/multi_filter.html